Error while starting Teamspeak 3 Client
I am trying to install team speak 3 client on a fresh installation of Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS.

downloaded the .run file from the Teamspeak website (https://teamspeak.com/en/downloads/#) Client 64-bit 3.6.2
start Terminal
cd ~/Downloads
chmod u+x TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.6.2.run
cd ~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/
try to start the ts3 client: ./ts3client_runscript.sh

Get following error:

QApplication object first qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt
platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application
failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland-egl, wayland,
wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

./ts3client_runscript.sh: line 11: 28454 Aborted                 (core
dumped) ./ts3client_linux_amd64 $@ ```


After googling the error I only found very outdated guides and when I found mentions of the error it was development related to other things then Teamspeak.
Can anyone help me to get this running?
